# Django DateTime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm using Django and when I retrieve instance (with `objects.all()`) the `models.DateTime` are changing so that 7 hours are added.

I'm in the US Pacific time zone and I'm guessing that my DB is defined as UTC I'm using PostgreSQL and I can't figure out where is the setting for time zone.

One other thing I'm also getting this warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime  while time zone support is active.

Maybe the two are connected?

Answer (score 2):

settings.py：

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
# database not use UTC
USE_TZ = False
```

see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql)